# Step in Lemma 2.20 of Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm struggling to understand the following step in proposition 2.20 of Lee's *Intro to Smooth Manifolds*:

[image]

---

Applying L'Hôpital's gives me either
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^{-1/t}}{t^k} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t^{-2}e^{-1/t}}{kt^{k-1}} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^{-1/t}}{kt^{k+1}},$$
or
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t^{-k}}{e^{1/t}} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{-kt^{k-1}}{-t^{-2}e^{1/t}} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{kt^{k+1}}{e^{1/t}}.$$
Neither of which gets me closer to $(2.2)$.

Answer (score 3):

In your last equation display, you made a differentiation error. The correct differentiation formula is
$$\frac{d}{dt} t^{-k} = -k t^{-k-1}
$$
And that, when multiplied by $t^2$, yields $-k t^{-k+1} = -k t^{-(k-1)}$. So your very last expression should be
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{kt^{-(k-1)}}{e^{1/t}} = k \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t^{-(k-1)}}{e^{1/t}}
$$
which, by the induction hypothesis, equals $0$.